# How to set malloc_error_break in Xcode4

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I am new to Xcode4, how to set malloc_error_break in Xcode4.

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x686a240: double free
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Comment: May be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796921/malloc-error-break-breakpoint-not-working

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If in Xcode 4, go to breakpoint navigator

> View/Navigators/Show Breakpoint Navigator

at the bottom, add a new breakpoint by clicking on the '+' plus sign and choose

> Add Symbolic Breakpoint

that you'll name it.... **"malloc_error_break"**

Comment: In already set it up but it keeps crashing on the dreaded NSApplicationMain(). I also have zombies enabled but nothing...

Comment: Do you need the surrounding quotes and asterisks? or is that just for emphasis?

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 4.5.2 its (From the menu bar):

Product, Debug, Create Symbolic Breakpoint