# double free*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug in ARC

Tags: iphone, multithreading, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease, double-free

I am using ARC in my application with core data and threading etc, after doing all that hard work to get core data work with threading without any crashes now I am getting a new crash with the reason-

```
double free*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

How am I supposed to handle this? I have no control on the objects' retain counts.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the objects' retain counts. This message is one of glibc's built-in error messages. This particular one points out that you've explicitly used free() on the same memory area twice.

Comment: No I haven't done anything like free() or malloc().

Comment: Then could you please provide a little more debugging information? Like some more error messages, maybe youl should compile with -g and do a backtrace in gdb etc. else we can't really help...

Comment: Where is your app stoping when you set the recommended breakpoint? That is a good area of the code to examine more closely.

Comment: @H2CO3 How do I get the backtrace as you were saying..

Comment: Compile the code with -g, then run it in gdb, then when it stops, type `backtrace` <enter>

Comment: I got a similar error when I forgot to mark a destructor `virtual` in a base class I was inheriting from (C++ segment of code).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Enable Zombie
2. Follow this link : http://iphone2020.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/capturing-exceptions-while-debugging/. This will suggest exact point of crash.

Comment: Use it only for testing purpose. While giving build remove the reference!!

Comment: That link seems to be down (never loads).  Can you maybe give some insight as to what needs to be done.  I have used Zombies in the past but not that extensively.  @NaveenThunga   (thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to know who destroyed the allocation:**

Simply breaking as the message suggests will give you clues.

**If you want to know who created the allocation:**

Although you can also do this from the command line using malloc stack logging, it may be a gentler introduction to use Instruments. Run the program with allocation recording enabled in instruments, reproduce the issue, then look up the address in instruments of the double free -- it will show you the backtrace of the allocation's creation. then figure why that allocation was freed twice.

Comment: Could you share the steps for adding the breakpoint for malloc_error_break?

Comment: @Gujamin i suspect you did not search first -- i entered `malloc_error_break` into stack overflow. the first result answers your question (step-by-step): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923853/how-to-set-malloc-error-break-in-xcode4

Comment: I had followed those steps (adding the `malloc_error_break` symbolic breakpoint) but it didn't stop anywhere in my code and again reported `*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`