# malloc_error_break to debug on NSString

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I have the following piece of code

```
 if([news.new_image isEqualToString:@""]){
        cell.imgNews.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
    }else{
        NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://genkonstage.genk.be/files/news/s_%@",news.new_image];
        [cell.imgNews setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                     placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    }
```

But every time I run it. I get the following error on the `NSString *url line`

```
genkonstage(56799,0x357f1a8) malloc: *** error for object 0xc4d1660: double free
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Could somebody please help me with this ?

*** I have enabled ARC in the project.

Thanks !

Comment: What value(format) you are getting from news.new_image string..?

Comment: It's a NSString in my core data

Comment: Can you refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045208/how-to-set-a-breakpoint-in-malloc-error-break-to-debug
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587266/double-free-set-a-breakpoint-in-malloc-error-break-to-debug-in-arc

Comment: Can't get my head around it. Even with the breakpoints

Comment: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/354 ?