# Malloc Crash when creating UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I know its a little bit general , but we did EVERY possible thing to find what it is, and we just couldn't .

We have this crash that happens here and there, not always, on this line :

```
[self.imageOperationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^
 {
    if(!data)
        return ;
    UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data]; // *** CRASH !
```

The crash log says :

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x7fecdb06e5c0: double free
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

As you can see, and upon our check , `data` is not nil when we are creating the image , we have also tried with :  `[UIImage   initWithData:data];` without allocation , but same thing.

EDIT:
this is how the code looks like after this row :

```
       if(!data)
          return ;


      UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
      UIImageView *modelview=[self.allImageView objectAtIndex:index];
      float newH=image.size.height* (1.65*modelview.frame.size.width/image.size.width);
      CGSize s=CGSizeMake(1.65*modelview.frame.size.width, newH);

      if (image)
      {
          UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(s , NO, 0.0);
          [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, s.width, s.height)];

          image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
          UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
      }
```

Comment: Yes, set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug and enable zombies

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587266/double-free-set-a-breakpoint-in-malloc-error-break-to-debug-in-arc go through this link.

Comment: why not simply [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data.copy] and see how it goes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587266/double-free-set-a-breakpoint-in-malloc-error-break-to-debug-in-arc?lq=1

Comment: I got this crash when the disk is full. Don't know how to solve it yet.

Answer (score 3):

Your `data` is likely being over-released on another thread. The double-free indicates a memory management imbalance, not a nil-pointer.

If I had to predict the problem, I'd guess you're generating `data` from an unsafe pointer, maybe the result of a CoreGraphics call, or a `NSData` over malloc'ed memory that gets freed behind your back. Here's how my theory works:

- You create the `NSData` over unsafe memory
- You create this operation block, which puts a retain on the `NSData`
- Somewhere else, you free the underlying memory
- The operation block runs
- This is the last line that uses `data`
- ARC notices that and so releases `data` at the semicolon
- Releasing `data` leads to a `free()`
- Memory was already freed by someone else
- Crash

The key is that `NSData` typically should be the sole owner of its memory; if it's not, then you have to be very careful, especially in multi-threaded operations.

Comment: thanks-Please check my edit : you right i do use core graphic right after that, but the crash shows that its that line . So , bottom line how would i change this code to stop this from happen ? every time i want to load 4 next images from a server i use this block( a regular lazy loading)

Comment: @Curnelious - By the time you get to the failing line it's too late.

Comment: The bug probably isn't here. It's probably in the code that generates data and then calls this.